# Unable to parse image URL from reddit json results

Tags: android, json, nullpointerexception, gson, retrofit2

Check [this for JSON DATA](https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/.json)

I want to parse `preview -> images ->source -> url`:

```
public class LChildData {

    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    public String title;

    @SerializedName("preview")
    @Expose
    public LPreview preview;

}

public class LPreview {

    @SerializedName("images")
    @Expose
    public List<LImages> images =null;
}

public class LImages {

    @SerializedName("source")
    @Expose
    public LSource source;
}

public class LSource {

    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    public String url;

}
```

**ViewHolder code**:

```
 if (isValidImageUrl(holder.mItem.data.preview.images.get(0).source.url)) {
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(holder.mItem.data.preview.images.get(0).source.url)
                .into(holder.mPostThumbnail);
    }
```

**Error**:

> D/ViewAdapter:onBindViewHolder: image_url 
>    :https://i.redditmedia.com/RoARvRoBJHQihiWK_aHdhEZG2kabxNvmvY5kZKFkskk.jpg?s=037d08a057a7a6d253ab0937b6247353
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
>    'java.util.List com.example.dex.redditclient.listings.model.LPreview.getImages()' on a null object reference                                                                              at com.example.dex.redditclient.listings.ViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ViewAdapter.java:60)

Comment: share your json response with question

Comment: Your json response get image null check response image get or not ?

Comment: `images` is obviously null -> absent in the JSON.

Comment: I got the Image URL but getting NullPointerException mention below